# How to call a SOAP webservice with a simple String (xml in string format)

Tags: java, android, web-services, soap, httpclient

I have this string representing a XML:

```
String soapCall="<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope" soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-encoding"> <soap:Body xmlns:m="http://www.example.org/stock"> <m:addDownloadParams> <m:idApp>";
soapCall+=idApp;
soapCall+="<m:versionApp>";
soapCall+=versonApp;
soapCall+="</m:versionApp> <m:os>Android</m:os> </m:addDownloadParams> </soap:Body> </soap:Envelope>";
```

And i have this soap webservice:

```
http://stats.mywebsite.com/ws/adddownload
```

Now, i need to pass that string to that soap webservice on android, but i dont know the way, i know i need to use httpcliente:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
```

but i dont know how to call the soapwebservice with that string.

Anyone haves a code example? i can't find it on google. I dont want to use a library, i need to do it by myself

Thanks

**EDIT: this is the code now, but it is not working, i get error 500 internal server error:**

```
    public static byte[] addDownloadIntoServer(){
        byte[] result = null;

        String SERVER_URL="http://stats.mywebsite.com/ws/server.php";
        String SOAP_ACTION="addDownload";
        String body="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:ns1=\"http://stats.mobincube.com/\"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:addDownloadParams>";
    body+="<idApp>" +SectionManager.instance.app_id+"</idApp>";
    body+="<versionApp>"+SectionManager.instance.app_version+"</versionApp>";
    body+="<source>android</source> <os>Android</os> </ns1:addDownloadParams></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>";

        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        // Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established.
        int timeoutConnection = 15000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
        // Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT)
        // in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
        int timeoutSocket = 35000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

        /*
        * httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials( new
        * AuthScope("os.icloud.com", 80, null, "Digest"), new
        * UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));
        */
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(SERVER_URL );
        httppost.setHeader("soapaction", SOAP_ACTION);
        httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");

        System.out.println("executing request" + httppost.getRequestLine());
        //now create a soap request message as follows:
        final StringBuffer soap = new StringBuffer();
        soap.append("\n");
        soap.append("");
        // this is a sample data..you have create your own required data  BEGIN
        soap.append(" \n");
        soap.append(" \n");
        soap.append("" + body);
        soap.append(" \n");
        soap.append(" \n");

        /* soap.append(body); */
        // END of MEssage Body
        soap.append("");
        Log.i("SOAP Request", ""+soap.toString());
        // END of full SOAP request  message
        try {
            HttpEntity entity = new StringEntity(soap.toString(),HTTP.UTF_8);
            httppost.setEntity(entity); 
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);// calling server
            HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();  //get response
            Log.i("Reponse Header", "Begin...");          // response headers
            Log.i("Reponse Header", "StatusLine:"+response.getStatusLine());
            Header[] headers = response.getAllHeaders();
            for(Header h:headers)
                Log.i("Reponse Header",h.getName() + ": " + h.getValue());

            Log.i("Reponse Header", "END...");
            if (r_entity != null) {       
                result = new byte[(int) r_entity.getContentLength()];  
                if (r_entity.isStreaming()) {
                    DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(
                    r_entity.getContent());
                    is.readFully(result);
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception E) {
            Log.i("Exception While Connecting", ""+E.getMessage());
            E.printStackTrace();
        }

        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown(); //shut down the connection
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution:

```
private byte[] callSOAPServer() {

    byte[] result = null;

    HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
    // Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established.
    int timeoutConnection = 15000;
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
    // Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT)
    // in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
    int timeoutSocket = 35000;
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

    /*
     * httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials( new
     * AuthScope("os.icloud.com", 80, null, "Digest"), new
     * UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));
     */
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(SERVER_URL );
    httppost.setHeader("soapaction", SOAP_ACTION);
    httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");

    System.out.println("executing request" + httppost.getRequestLine());
   //now create a soap request message as follows:
    final StringBuffer soap = new StringBuffer();
    soap.append("\n");
    soap.append("");
   // this is a sample data..you have create your own required data  BEGIN
    soap.append(" \n");
    soap.append(" \n");
    soap.append("" + body);
    soap.append(" \n");
    soap.append(" \n");

    /* soap.append(body); */
     // END of MEssage Body
    soap.append("");
    Log.i("SOAP Request", ""+soap.toString());
   // END of full SOAP request  message
    try {
        HttpEntity entity = new StringEntity(soap.toString(),HTTP.UTF_8);
        httppost.setEntity(entity); 
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);// calling server
        HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();  //get response
        Log.i("Reponse Header", "Begin...");          // response headers
        Log.i("Reponse Header", "StatusLine:"+response.getStatusLine());
        Header[] headers = response.getAllHeaders();
        for(Header h:headers){
            Log.i("Reponse Header",h.getName() + ": " + h.getValue());
        }
        Log.i("Reponse Header", "END...");
        if (r_entity != null) {       
            result = new byte[(int) r_entity.getContentLength()];  
            if (r_entity.isStreaming()) {
                DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(
                        r_entity.getContent());
                is.readFully(result);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception E) {
        Log.i("Exception While Connecting", ""+E.getMessage());
        E.printStackTrace();
    }

    httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown(); //shut down the connection
    return result;
   }
```

2) You have to parse the output of above function returned byteArray. For example:

```
byte[] initReqrepsonse = callSOAPServer(soapBodymessage );
ByteArrayInputStream bais=new ByteArrayInputStream(initReqrepsonse);
// now parse the xml as
/** Handling XML */
SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

/** Create handler to handle XML Tags ( extends DefaultHandler ) */
// ResponseParser  is XML parser class which will parse the XML output.
ResponseParser myXMLHandler = new ResponseParser();
xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
Log.i("XML data", bais.toString());
xr.parse(new InputSource(bais));
```

This way,you can access Any SOAP webservice methods without third-party libraries.
Please let me know if any corrections are required.

Comment: What should i do with " // this is a sample data..you have create your own required data  BEGIN"  and also, i need to mantain all these /n appends on soap string?. I'm getting error code 500, internal server error

Comment: i edited my question with my current code using your solution, please check it, something is not working

Comment: <faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">a:ActionNotSupported</faultcode><faultstring xml:lang="en-US">The message with Action 'Register' cannot be processed at the receiver,due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher.This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements,e.g. Message,Transport,None).</faultstring>

Comment: @Shyam, I am using your code but getting above response, I could not post all the response string due to character limi here, sorry. can you tell me why this would be?

Comment: @sachin10 please see my quetion, can you tell me this type of solution?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29231074/how-to-set-soap-header-using-ksoap-on-android

Answer (score 1):

```
Formatted answer :


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod;

/**
 * * This program demonstrates consuming web service using Apache HTTPClient and
 * SOAP message. * Reference:
 * http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?op=GetQuote * ClassPath: Keep these
 * two files in class path: commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar, commons-codec-1.4.jar * @author
 * Bhavani P Polimetla * @since April-27-2011
 */
public class WSClient {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.getParams().setParameter("http.useragent",
                "Web Service Test Client");
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String data = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?> "
                + "<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap12=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\">   "
                + "<soap12:Body>     "
                + "<GetQuote xmlns=\"http://www.webserviceX.NET/\">       "
                + "<symbol>INFY</symbol>     " + "</GetQuote>   "
                + "</soap12:Body> </soap12:Envelope>";
        PostMethod methodPost = new PostMethod(
                "http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?op=GetQuote");
        methodPost.setRequestBody(data);
        methodPost.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
        try {
            int returnCode = httpClient.executeMethod(methodPost);
            if (returnCode == HttpStatus.SC_NOT_IMPLEMENTED) {
                System.out
                        .println("The Post method is not implemented by this URI");
                methodPost.getResponseBodyAsString();
            } else {
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        methodPost.getResponseBodyAsStream()));
                String readLine;
                while (((readLine = br.readLine()) != null)) {
                    System.out.println(readLine);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            methodPost.releaseConnection();
            if (br != null)             try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (Exception fe) {
                    fe.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to parse the response of this call?

Answer (score 0):

```
package ProductVerificationCard.in;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;``
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AdminLogin extends Activity {
 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
Button btn_ok;
TextView textView;
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/Login";

private static final String OPERATION_NAME = "Login";

private static final String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";

private static final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://10.0.2.2/new/WebService.asmx";
String s;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    btn_ok=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
    textView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_error);

    btn_ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,
                    OPERATION_NAME);

                    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                    SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                    envelope.dotNet = true;

                    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

                    HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);

                    try

                    {

                    httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

                    Object response = envelope.getResponse();

                    //textView.setText(response.toString());
                     s=response.toString();
                     if(s=="true")
                     {
                         Intent intent=new Intent(AdminLogin.this,MenuForm.class);
                            startActivity(intent);

                     }

                     else
                     {
                         textView.setText("Enter Valid Username or Password");
                     }
                    }

                    catch (Exception exception)

                    {

                    textView.setText(exception.toString());

                    }
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
       });

    }
  }
```