# HTTPGET request of a soap webservice in java application

Tags: java, soap, http-get

I had written a method in soap web service  which returns the data from database. now i am facing the problem to write HTTP GET request in java application. Any help and suggestions will be appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why you are not using jax-ws or apache axis2 or apache CXF for consuming your webbservice ? Direct http invoke will be little tricky and you will required to construct your soap message and some http headers to call soap based service directly http client. check the http client for soap service here [How to call a SOAP webservice with a simple String (xml in string format)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561503/how-to-call-a-soap-webservice-with-a-simple-string-xml-in-string-format)